# C++: Matrix Gauss Elimination Does Not Work: Using SINGLE DIMENSION Array to store elements

Tags: c++

my codes does not work for Gauss Elimination for Matrix. The core code is ok, but it seems to be missing some final touch which I honestly dont know. Would be great if someone can point out the mistake.

Basically when I input a square 3x3 Matrix filled with 3s, I get back (3, 3, 3, 0, -3, -3, 0, 0, 3) but it should be (3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

n is number of rows of matrix and m is number of columns.

All elements of matrix are stored in a SINGLE DIMENSION array called entries[i]

My code below for GaussElimination basically starts with placing the row with the largest first element on the top row. Then after that I just delete the elements right below the top elements.

```
Matrix Matrix::GaussElim() const {
    double maxEle;
    int maxRow;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        maxEle = fabs(entries[i-1]);
        maxRow = i;
        for (int k = i+1; k <= m; k++) {
            if (fabs(entries[(k - 1) * n + i - 1]) > maxEle) {
                maxEle = entries[(k - 1) * n + i - 1];
                maxRow = k;
            }
        }
        for (int a = 1; a <= m; a++) {
            swap(entries[(i - 1) * m + a - 1], entries[(maxRow - 1) * m + a - 1]);
        }
        for (int b = i + 1; b <= n; b++) {
            double c = -(entries[(b - 1) * m + i - 1]) / entries[(i - 1) * m + i - 1];
            for (int d = i; d <= n; d++) {
                if (i == d) {
                    entries[(b - 1) * m + d - 1] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    entries[(b - 1) * m + d - 1] = c * entries[(i - 1) * m + d - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix Result(n, m, entries);
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: you should debug the code and see where it goes wrong

Comment: Please provide the definition of entries and Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'd suggest to drop the habit of starting the loops at 1 instead of the more idiomatic 0, it would simplify all of the formulas.

That said, this statement

```
else {
    entries[(b - 1) * m + d - 1] = c * entries[(i - 1) * m + d - 1];
    //                          ^^^
}
```

Looks suspicious. There should be a `+=` (or a `-=`, depending on how you choose the sign of the pivot).

Another source of unexpected results is the way chosen to calculate the constant `c`:

```
double c = -(entries[(b - 1) * m + i - 1]) / entries[(i - 1) * m + i - 1];
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Even in case of partial pivoting, that value could be zero (or too small), due to the nature of the starting matrix, like in the posted example, or to numerical errors. In those cases, it would be preferable to just zero out all the remaining elements of the matrix.

Comment: Thanx bob, it is almost ok now based on your suggestion. However my last element shows -nan(ind). do you know why is that so? Basically when I input a square 3x3 Matrix filled with 3s, I get back (3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -nan(ind)) but it should be (3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @ChenJGThomas That's because you've chosen a non invertible matrix (its rank is less than the n). When i = 1, all the elements of column where are you searching the pivot are already 0, so that c become nan. If you want that output you should use something like `c = pivot != 0 ? .../pivot_value : 0;`